# Is an answer with proposed, but unadopted, code syntax low quality?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts, code

I saw someone answer a question yesterday with draft PHP RFC code

[Static class initializer in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312806/static-class-initializer-in-php/37819109#37819109)

It was in the LQR and I said it was OK (it does attempt to answer the question), but I went back to downvote it and comment it was a bad answer. Now I'm wondering if I should have voted for deletion. Sometimes people will use draft RFCs to move forward (like IEEE RFCs) but in PHP, RFCs are used to determine what code will be implemented. Sometimes it's even helpful to referent PHP RFCs that have been accepted for future inclusion, but this draft RFC doesn't even have an official implementation yet. It may never get out of draft.

The danger here is that someone might think this code is available for use. Someone edited the answer to include that this is proposed/draft code, but will new coders even understand what that means?

Comment: Related: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The danger here is that someone might think this code is available for use. Someone edited the answer to include that this is proposed/draft code, but will new coders even understand what that means?

Those are all reasons to downvote an answer.  They don't make it merit deletion.  Answers aren't deleted for being *wrong*, they're deleted because they're *not actually answers at all*.